# How to succesfully pass a 2D array to a function?

Tags: c, arrays

GNU GCC compiler
Here is a function: `int sumsintriangle(int *a,int n)`
where a is a n*n matrix  .
  for some purpose I added

```
if(*(a+(i+1)*n+(j+1)) > *(a+(i+1)*n+j))
```

condition to my code which was working properly ;as the condition is  true for the correct values.
   but for the same code when I added

```
sum=sum + *(a+(i+1)*n+(j+1));
```

then it didn't work (eg;let say sum was initially 1 and `*(a+(i+1)*n+(j+1)` was 4 ) then summation it should be giving me 5..but it gives me 1 as output...why??
 Even ,when I called the same value `*(a+(i+1)*n+(j+1))` in `printf` function,for just an enquiry, it is giving me 4 (original value)as output ...?

Why it is  , that `*(a+(i+1)*n+(j+1))` is working properly with `printf` but when I  called it with sum it gives me incorrect value?

Comment: Here N is what indicate?

Comment: Please show your attempted code, properly formatted. The stackoverflow.com help describes how to format.

Comment: You need to show more of the code (but still, not *all* of your code), e.g. I suppose you have a for cycle to parse your matrix, there might be some problems with the boundaries. It's actually **very strange** that you have to add 1 to the indexes. You have also show how/when you initialize sum.

Comment: Why not use: `a[(i+1))*n+(j+1)]`?  With modern compilers and modern optimizers, you should get the same results. Try a benchmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can post your function properly it could be easier to help you. but i think you  have an error when you put * before your expression that will give you the content of that expression, so be sure to get the values properly. 
example:

```
      int a[]; //declare an array
      a[n] // will give you the element in position 9 of the array.
      *a // will give you the first element, cause an array can be treated as a pointer (indeed it is).
```

I hope this answer help you. If not please tell me. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use This code code may be its work.

```
*(a+(i+1))*n+(j+1)
```

Comment: please paste your code here.. so i can give you proper solution.